# SimpleXMLElement - addChild instance

Tags: php, xml

I have 2 instances of SimpleXmlElement, for example:

```
$xmlMain = new SimpleXmlElement('<user><name></name></user>');

$xmlPart = new SimpleXmlElement('<user_details...</user_details>');
```

Can I insert `$xmlPart` element somewhere inside `$xmlMain`.

I want the result to be to inject `$xmlPart` instance inside `$xmlMain`, so the result would be

```
<user><name><user_details>...</user_details></name></user>
```

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML isn't very good at copying data from one node to another.  You can instead use the DOMDocument methods by first importing the SimpleXMLElements into DOMNodes, you then import the second node into the document for the first node and then append it to the name element...

```
$xmlMain = new SimpleXmlElement('<user><name></name></user>');

$xmlPart = new SimpleXmlElement('<user_details>...</user_details>');

// Import xmlMain <name> element into a DOMNode
$xmlMD = dom_import_simplexml($xmlMain->name);
// Import xmlPart into DOMNode and then import that node into the xmlMD document
$importedNode = $xmlMD->ownerDocument->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($xmlPart), true);
// Add the imported node into the first node (the <name> element)
$xmlMD->appendChild($importedNode);

echo $xmlMain->asXML();
```

This will give...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user><name><user_details>...</user_details></name></user>
```

An alternative which could be simpler is to create the `$xmlPart` element in the `$xmlMain` document in the first place...

```
$xmlMain = new SimpleXmlElement('<user><name></name></user>');
$userDetails = $xmlMain->name->addChild("user_details");
$userDetails->addChild("name", "Fred");

echo $xmlMain->asXML();
```

creates...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user><name><user_details><name>Fred</name></user_details></name></user>
```